# set theory addition principle (proof by contradiction)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I'm trying to use proof by contradiction to prove the addition principle for sets. So,

If $|A \cup B| = |A|+|B|$, then $A \cap B = \emptyset$.

Does this make sense? -

Let $A$ and $B$ be sets. Suppose that $A \cap B \neq \emptyset$. If $A \cap B \neq \emptyset$ then $|A \cup B| = |A|+|B|+|A \cap B|$ because the union of A and B is defined as all $x \in A$ or $x \in B$.

Is this the correct way to start it?

Comment: Its almost done. Suppose $ x \in A \cap B $ then $x \in A$ and $x \in B$ now what happens to the amount of elements on both sides?

Comment: $|A \cup B| = |A|+|B|\color{red}-|A \cap B|$.  And that's *always* true, regardless of whether $A \cap B = \emptyset$ or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the right way. One way to go is:

Assume that the equation holds and $A \cap B \not = \emptyset$. Then:

$$|A \cup B| = |A| + |B| > |A| + |B| - |A \cap B| = |A \cup B|$$

Obviously this is impossible and hence we obtain the wanted contradiction.